# Object reference not set to an instance of an object c# Mysql -> DataSet -> CrystalReport

Tags: crystal-reports, dataset

I'm trying to display my data from `MySqlDatabase` to my `CrystalReport`. I've tried different ways but still get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I named my `DataSet` as ReportDataSet, I also created a table with the exact same Name, Content & DataType as my MySqlDatabase.

```
        MySqlConnection connection;
        MySqlCommand command;
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
        string con = "";

        private void report_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = "Server = localhost; Database = sample_inventory; Uid = root";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(con);
            connection.Open();

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "select * from tbl_account";
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                ReportDataSet ds = new ReportDataSet();
                ds.Clear();
                adapter.Fill(ds, "tbl_account");

                // Create a CrystalReport1
                CrystalReport1 myReport = new CrystalReport1();
                // Set the DataSource 
                myReport.SetDataSource(ds);
                // Report Source to ReportView 
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport; 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Where did the error occurred?

Comment: as soon as I execute the button_click_event

Comment: at where portion of your code?